# Why is my computer acting so weird about turning on?

Tags: computer-behavior

My computer has been acting extremely strange lately. Around two months ago, it stopped working. I mean entirely. I would plug it in, and turn it on, and the startup `*beep*` didn't happen. It would *charge* my iPod but not *connect* to it. I tried replacing the power supply and it didn't work.

Nobody plugged it back in, they just left it on the other side of the room. Then at the beginning of spring break, I plugged it back in and it worked, astonishingly. On Thursday it broke down again. Same situation, same symptoms. I took it to Best Buy, and they couldn't fix it. Again, left it on the other side of the room, unplugged. Today, 2/28, I plugged it back in on a gut feeling and I'm sitting here typing this right now, aren't I?

I suspect it will break down again and moving it around while leaving it unplugged for a week or two will fix it *again*. Some of you will say what am I complaining about, I know how to make it work. However, I need to use it more than just 4 days out of 14 (or whatever). Anyone know the problem or how to fix it?

Comment: I suggest finding a REAL tech (IE Not Best Buy) and have them take a look at it.   Do you have any small computer shops in town?  Best Buy (geek squad) has a very bad record in regard to being able to fix anything technological.  Your issue is too hard to diagnose without being able to actually have my hands on your computer.   It is obviously not a software issue, I know that much :)

Comment: Assuming you didn't mess around inside the computer (and accidentally take off a cable or a needed component), there can be at least 2 things wrong. Either the computer shows signs of old age or one of the memory modules has come loose. The 2nd one is easier to check. Remember to fasten the modules (if possible) with the plastic clamps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like loose component/cable inside.

Probably the HDD it self.

Open it and check for loose connectors.